# Difference between snap and snapd

Tags: command-line, package-management

All have read so far is that packages are named **snap** & the tool that uses them is called **snapd**.

Despite having a good idea of how snap package work, have no idea what is **snapd**.

Can you explain to me?

Answer (score 4):

From the [official documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs):

- **snap** is both the command line interface and the application package format
- **snapd** is the background service that manages and maintains your snaps (if you want to check service status run: `systemctl status snapd.service`, if you want to install/remove snap, you need to install/remove the package `snapd`)
- **snapcraft** is the command and the framework used to build your own snaps
- **[Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/store)** provides a place to upload your snaps, and for users to browse and install

Comment: Why would I wanna check the service status ? @ArturMeinild

Comment: Maybe if you're having trouble with the snap daemon? It was just a piece of extra info. If everything is running fine there is no need.

Comment: CHECKING MY SERVICE'S STATUS ? @Archisman

Comment: WOULD LIKE TO KNOW MORE ABT THE SNAP PACKAGE.                   WHEN REMOVING SOFTWARE USING APT, HAVE TO RUN REMOVE + PURGE @ArturMeinild

Comment: Please don't use all caps - it's the online equivalent of shouting.

Comment: @DBG If you want to know something about snaps, you can ask a new question in Ask Ubuntu, mentioning specifically what you want to know (but first ask your favorite search engine).